# Como mudar o valor do TextField do MaterialUI durante um teste usando testing-library e formik (react app)?

Tags: react, typescript, testes, material-ui, formik

### Estou usando:

- formik
- testing-library
- materialUI (TextField)
- @testing-library/jest-dom

Eu tentei mudar o valor do TExtFIeld do MaterialUI durante o tempo de execução do teste de diferentes formas mas nenhuma funcionou

### Meu form:

#### Deixei só o campo de email, pq só estou querendo testar ele

```js
<FormikProvider value={formik}>
  <Form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={formStyles}>
    <TextField 
      fullWidth
      autoComplete="email"
      type="email"
      label="Email"
      variant="filled"
      color='primary'
      data-testid="email"
      sx={{
        background: palette.primary.lighter,
      }}
      inputProps={{'data-testid': 'emailInput'}}
      error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
      helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
    />
  </Form>
</FormikProvider>
```

### Meu teste:

```js
const mockedOnSubmit = (values: ISignupValues, actions: FormikHelpers<ISignupValues>) => jest.fn()
const setup = () => render(mockUsingDefaultWrappers(<SignupForm handleSubmitProp={mockedOnSubmit} />))
const getBtnSignup = (screen: any) => screen.getByRole('button', {name: /cadastrar/i})

it('should show an error message if the user does not type the email properly', async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    setup()
    const btnSignup = getBtnSignup(screen)
    const emailInput = screen.getByTestId('emailInput')
    screen.debug(emailInput)
    userEvent.type(emailInput, 'asd')
    fireEvent.change(emailInput, {target: {value: 'asd'}});
    (emailInput as HTMLInputElement).value = 'asd'
    screen.debug(emailInput)
    fireEvent.click(btnSignup)
    await waitFor(async () => {
      await screen.findByText(/Nome completo obrigatório/i)
      console.log('clicked', !!screen.queryByText(/Nome completo obrigatório/i))
      console.log('invalid:', !!screen.queryByText(/Endereço de e-mail inválido/i))
      console.log('null:', !!screen.queryByText(/E-mail obrigatorio/i))
    })
  })
  // expect(await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/Endereço de e-mail inválido/i))).toBeVisible()
})
```

#### Os console.logs fazem o seguinte:

- "clicked" verifica se o botao de cadastro foi clicado
- "invalid" verifica se o input de email foi preenchido com um email invalido
- "null" verifica se o input de email está vazio

##### O objetivo é conseguir mudar o value do TextField simulando um usuário real tentando se cadastrar

### debug results:

#### antes de mudar o value do TextField:

```html
<input
  aria-invalid="false"
  autocomplete="email"
  class="MuiFilledInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-1eujsfn-MuiInputBase-input-MuiFilledInput-input"
  data-testid="emailInput"
  type="email"
  value=""
/>
```

#### depois de mudar o TextField:

```html
<input
  aria-invalid="false"
  autocomplete="email"
  class="MuiFilledInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-1eujsfn-MuiInputBase-input-MuiFilledInput-input"
  data-testid="emailInput"
  type="email"
  value=""
/>
```

### console.log responses:

- clicked: true
- invalid: false
- null: true

### console.log responses esperadas:

- clicked: true
- invalid: true
- null: false

Answer (score 0):

### Aparentemente existe um delay ao atualizar o value do TextField usando formik para resolver bastas usar `waitFor()` do jest

##### Também é recomendado usar `eventFire.submit()` ao envés de `eventFire.click()` no botão de ação do formuçário

```js
it('should show an error message if the user does not type the email properly', async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    setup()
    const btnSignup = getBtnSignup(screen)
    const emailInput = screen.getByTestId('emailInput')
    
    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.change(emailInput, {target: {value: 'asd'}})
    })

    fireEvent.submit(btnSignup)
  })
  expect(await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/Endereço de e-mail inválido/i))).toBeVisible() //passes now
})
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).